# list.contains() is not working in android

Tags: android, arraylist

list.contains is not working.
Here is my list which gets data from database.

```
////////List/////////////////
public List<Comment> getAllComments() {
        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
                allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
            comments.add(comment);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        return comments;
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////





    datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();
        final List list;
        list = datasource.getAllComments();

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
if(list.contains("Hello")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List Contains data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } ///////Here it always return false///////
else{
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
            }
        });
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

My list contais Hello but i don't know why its not working. & sorry if it is already asked. The thing is i want some example code, regarding my codes Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you print your list and paste it here?

Comment: `list` contains objects from type `Comment`, but "Hello" is a String.

Comment: yes Hello is a string and I'm trying to compare a string to list element. But its not working furthermore there isn't any problem in retriving data i have checked millions time.

Comment: The point here is that you are comparing String with an object of Comment. Thats why contains is returning false;

Comment: @Abdul.Moqueet You have to cast the String into a Comment object or you have to override the `equals` method from your Comment class to compare it with String objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you have to override **equals()** method inside **Comment** class.
Something like

```
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     if (this.message.equals(((Comment)obj).getMessage()) {
         return true;
     }

     return false;
 }
```

In this sample, *message* would be the property of your class that you would like to compare, and you could do it as follows

```
if(list.contains(new Comment("Hello")){
   ...
```

Regards!

Comment: I know, it's just an example of how it would be done

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
boolean contains = false;
        for (Comment c : list) {
            if (c.text.equals("H")) 
                contains = true;
        }
```